# Event object always has relatedTarget undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

bootstrap events provide us `event.relatedTarget` inside the available events. 
I am using `shown.bs.modal`. In normal cases `event.relatedTarget` has the button object from where we click and activate the modal by using onlick event on the button like below.

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
  $("#modalId").modal('toggle');
});
```

then we can use the following way to get the button

```
$('#modalId').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
});
```

Now i am working on a filemanager plugin in which i have context menu binding on the browsed files, and inside the context menu i have a menu item `Rename` , when i click on rename i have to open the modal window and send the file name that I have to rename. I can send the filename via context menu options selection i.e by clicking on the Rename option i can get the object of the file div which has the filename inside the attribute id, but this will not help because i need the file div object inside the bootstrap shown event and i am opening the modal by calling the function 
`openRenameWindow(#clickedFileDivObject);` from with in the context menu call back function and inside the function i open the modal like below

```
function openRenameWindow{
   $("#rename-file").modal('toggle');
}
```

now the problem is when i bind the event for the `shown.bs.modal` the event object always have the `relatedTarget` undefined . Can someone guide me how can i get the filename there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding, you need to pass something to your modal window, if I understood wrongly please correct me by adding a comment.

Simplest solution:

Your problem caused as you did not pass the `button` object as a second param when you toggled the modal window for show/display:

```
//pass button object 
$("#rename-file").modal('toggle', $("#buttonId"));
```

You can do the following scenario too:

Each link should have a class `.rename` and you can save `fileName` as data attribute in your button or a div next to your button, when you open the modal window pass the `fileName` as a data attribute to it.

```
$(".rename").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var fileName = $(this).data("file");
    $("#basicModal").data("fileName", fileName).modal("toggle", $this);

});

$("#basicModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e){
  //data-fileName attribute associated with the modal added in the click event of the button
  alert($(this).data("fileName"));
  //my data-file associated with the button 
  alert($(e.relatedTarget).data("file"));
})
```

[Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/EwdKYa) for both solutions:

If you need more options in modal windows, Here is a [library](http://bscom.msoliman.me/modals/) that I wrote based on `Bootstrap 4`

Comment: thanks that was it i was looking into bootstrap js documentation, totally overlooked that i could do it via jquery, thanks for help